# Next integer greater than but not equal to input

Tags: matlab, ceil

Is there a (Matlab) function similar to [`ceil`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) to find the next integer that is greater than the input but *not equal* to the input?

Examples:

```
1.1 --> 2
1.9 --> 2
2.0 --> 3    (note that ceil(2) == 2)
2.1 --> 3
```

I tried with `ceil(x+eps)`, but that only works for small numbers:

```
>> ceil((-4:4)+eps)

ans =

-4    -3    -1     0     1     2     2     3     4
```

Also, any equivalent for `floor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to treat negative and positive values alike, such that `1.1` becomes `2` and `-1.1` becomes `1`, then [the answer from informaton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204401/52738) using [`floor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) is correct:

```
out = floor(x)+1;
```

If you'd rather have positive values become the next-most positive integer, but negative values become the next-most *negative* integer, then you can use [`fix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) and [`sign`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) like so:

```
out = fix(x)+sign(x);
```

For example:

```
>> x = [-2.1 -2.0 -1.9 -1.1 0 1.1 1.9 2.0 2.1]

x =
   -2.1000   -2.0000   -1.9000   -1.1000         0    1.1000    1.9000    2.0000    2.1000

>> out = fix(x)+sign(x)

out =
    -3    -3    -2    -2     0     2     2     3     3
```

Answer (score 3):

For positive numbers x:

`floor(x)+1`

The second question is a little ambiguous without the examples, but this may be what you are looking for:

`ceil(x)-1`